# need return after navigation.goback()?

Tags: react-navigation

With React Navigation 5.x, shall return be used after navigation.goBack() in the code snippet below?

```
if (condition_met) {
    setTimeout(()=> {
     navigation.goBack();
     return;  //<<==needed after navigation or useless/never executed?
   }, 1000);
 }
 //do something else if above condition not met.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function called by `setTimeout` is executed after `// do something else`.

Move the `return` statement outside of `setTimeout`

```
if (condition_met) {
  setTimeout(()=> {
    navigation.goBack();     
  }, 1000);

  return;  //condition met stop executing code further
}

//do something else if above condition not met.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is normally advised to handle such effects in the return function of a useEffect as that is called when a component is being closed.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // cleanup code codes here
    };
  },[]);
```

This will work after the `navigation.goBack()` closes the screen component.